# User inputted key breaks regex when fetch CoreData entities with NSPredicate MATCHES

Tags: ios, regex, core-data

We use below `NSPredicate` to fetch entities from `CoreData`:

```
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"name MATCHES[cd] %@", [NSString stringWithFormat:@"^%@.*|.*[-\\s.@]%@.*", userInputtedKey, userInputtedKey]];
```

Everything goes well if `userInputtedKey` contains, for example, only letters and numbers. However, if `userInputtedKey` itself contains reserved symbol for regex, then, match will fail and even crash.

For example, `userInputtedKey` as `@"("` will lead to crash:

> *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Can't do regex matching,
>   reason: Can't open pattern U_REGEX_MISMATCHED_PAREN (string Yu,
>   pattern ^(.*|.*[-\s.@](.*, case 1, canon 2)'

The content of `userInputtedKey` is out of my control; it can be anything input by user. Is it possible to let the system to not parse the reserved symbol if any inside `userInputtedKey`, just treat the `userInputtedKey` as a whole for matching? Something like quoting `''`?

Answer (score 2):

Finally found a graceful solution, which is:
    userInputtedKey = [NSRegularExpression escapedPatternForString: userInputtedKey];

Answer (score 0):

Encountered the same issue. **Swift 4** version:

```
let safeUserInputtedKey = NSRegularExpression.escapedPattern(for: userInputtedKey)
```